# how to bring the list of multiple files into listctrl python

Tags: python, wxpython, listctrl

[wxpython add folder to listctrl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515591/wxpython-add-folder-to-listctrl)

According to the link, I tried to make a code adding files into listctrl.
But it  didn't work.

```
def OnButtonPath(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyDialog.<event_handler>
    dlg = wx.DirDialog(self, "Choose Directory...", \
                       style = wx.DD_DEFAULT_STYLE|wx.DD_DIR_MUST_EXIST)
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        self.listCtrl.Value = path = dlg.GetPath()
        #self.AddtoList(path)
    dlg.Destroy()

def AddToList(self, path):
    fname = os.path.basename(path)  # insert only folder-name
    self.listCtrlFile.Append(fname)
```

If I activate belows, I can't open python GUI.

> self.AddtoList(path)

just what I want is to bring multiple files into listctrl.
How Can I do this?

================== Entire Code ==================

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
#
# generated by wxGlade 0.6.8 (standalone edition) on Thu Jul 31 17:55:10 2014
#

import wx

# begin wxGlade: dependencies
import gettext
# end wxGlade

# begin wxGlade: extracode
# end wxGlade


class MyDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # begin wxGlade: MyDialog.__init__
        kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.labelPath = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, _("Path : "))
        self.textCtrlPath = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.button_1 = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, _("Open..."))
        self.labelFile = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, _("File List :"))
        self.listCtrlFile = wx.ListCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.LC_REPORT | wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.buttonAccept = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, _("RUN"))
        self.buttonExit = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, _("EXIT"))

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButtonPath, self.button_1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButtonAccept, self.buttonAccept)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButtonExit, self.buttonExit)
        # end wxGlade

    def __set_properties(self):
        # begin wxGlade: MyDialog.__set_properties
        self.SetTitle(_("test"))
        self.textCtrlPath.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(255, 255, 255))
        # end wxGlade

    def __do_layout(self):
        # begin wxGlade: MyDialog.__do_layout
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        footerSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        pathSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        pathSizer.Add(self.labelPath, 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 2)
        pathSizer.Add(self.textCtrlPath, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT | wx.EXPAND, 3)
        pathSizer.Add(self.button_1, 0, 0, 0)
        mainSizer.Add(pathSizer, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 4)
        mainSizer.Add(self.labelFile, 0, wx.ALL, 6)
        mainSizer.Add(self.listCtrlFile, 7, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 4)
        footerSizer.Add(self.buttonAccept, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT | wx.EXPAND, 3)
        footerSizer.Add(self.buttonExit, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT | wx.EXPAND, 3)
        mainSizer.Add(footerSizer, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_RIGHT, 2)
        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)
        mainSizer.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()
        # end wxGlade

    def OnButtonPath(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyDialog.<event_handler>
        dlg = wx.DirDialog(self, "Choose a directory:")
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.textCtrlPath.Value = dlg.GetPath()
        dlg.Destroy()

    def OnButtonAccept(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyDialog.<event_handler>
        print "Event handler 'OnButtonAccept' not implemented!"
        event.Skip()

    def OnButtonExit(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyDialog.<event_handler>
        self.Destroy()

# end of class MyDialog
if __name__ == "__main__":
    gettext.install("test") # replace with the appropriate catalog name

    test = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
    wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
    mainDialog = MyDialog(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
    test.SetTopWindow(mainDialog)
    mainDialog.Show()
    test.MainLoop()
```

Comment: could you provide your entire code?

Comment: I added the entire code. I just want make a code with clicking button, and importing file list into "listCtrlFile"

Answer (score 1):

You can do this quite easily by using Python's glob module to grab all the file paths in the folder that is chosen via the `DirDialog`. Once you have the list of paths, you can iterate over those and use the list control's `InsertStringItem` method to add the filename to the first column. Here's a simple example:

```
import glob
import os
import wx

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(self, 
                                     style=wx.LC_REPORT
                                     |wx.BORDER_SUNKEN
                                     )
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, 'Filename')

        btn = wx.Button(self, label="Open Folder")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onOpenDirectory)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onOpenDirectory(self, event):
        """"""
        dlg = wx.DirDialog(self, "Choose a directory:")
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            path = dlg.GetPath()
            self.updateDisplay(path)
        dlg.Destroy()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def updateDisplay(self, folder_path):
        """
        Update the listctrl with the file names in the passed in folder
        """
        paths = glob.glob(folder_path + "/*.*")
        for index, path in enumerate(paths):
            self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(index, os.path.basename(path))


########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Add Files")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Note that I used Python's `os` module to grab just the file's name instead of inserting the entire path into the list control. If you want to get fancy, you could add additional columns to show the file's size, date, etc, which you can get from `os.stat`